# What game does this die belong to?

Tags: identify-this-game

Have a game die and I am trying to figure out which game it belongs to.
Has the numbers 1, 2,3, 2 and " All HOP Over" and "Turn Log"

Ideas?

Answer (score 9):

Looks like it's [Frogger](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/6598/frogger), a board game based on the video game. A picture of the die from there:

[image: frogger die]

And the game:

[image: frogger game] [image]

(I found this by searching on Google for ["all hop over" "turn log"] - the single result is of all things [a patent for the game](http://www.google.com/patents/US4534566).)

Comment: I was about to post a link to the patent; which I'd also found. But how did you get from the patent info to that game? I hadn't found anything further.

Comment: @Gendolkari, Recognizing the (video) game represented by the illustration in the patent and/or reading the second-to-last paragraph of the patent would do it.

Comment: @GendoIkari Yup, I skimmed through, thought "this sounds kinda like Frogger", saw the mention at the bottom, then went back and confirmed it on BoardGameGeek. (Fortunately there were pictures there.)